# What do we call a person who makes up facts in order to look smart

Tags: word-request

My discourse is like this:

> However, sometimes knowledge could be abused. People should be aware because there are ____ who make up facts in order to look smart instead of admitting their ignorances.

It'd be awkward if I repeat "people", that's why I need a word to define this type of people.

I've found such words like *sophists* and *pathological liars*. But they aren't suitable here.

These people don't make up facts for an argument but they just want to look smart and convincing. They also give fake statistics such as "90% of people are...", "20% of our blood is..".

Comment: "Phatological" is amusing, but spurious. "Ignorances" is not a correct plural in English. Perhaps _liar_ is the word you seek. In any case, any answer to your question will be opinion-based.

Comment: @P.E.Dant "ignorances" appears in my Merriam-Webster search. Do you mean I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: A *phrase* that is used to describe such a person is: "seldom correct, but never in doubt".  It also depends if you are assuming there is intent by the person, that they know they are making up statistics instead of just ignorance and not knowing the correct statistic.

Comment: "Ignorances" does have a plural form; you're right. But the rest of my comment is accurate.

Comment: Try *wannabes*, *fakers*, *phonies*, or possibly *posers*.

Comment: @Peter it's more like an idiomatic expression

Comment: @LawrenceC Thank you for these words, I think I could use *posers* for now before other answers emerge

Comment: Note that it should be *make up facts* instead of *make up fact*

Comment: @Glorfindel my bad, thank you. I'm always careless with this.

Comment: **pseudointellectuals**  (one word or hyphenated) is not too bad a word, but they don't necessarily invent facts, they "pretend" to *know* facts, and their speech will contain all sorts of fancy and difficult to understand words. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pseudointellectual

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think I could use it for now  thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a handy little pronoun, **those**.

...there are those who...

P.S. I would also recommend "sometimes ... can be abused" rather than "sometimes ... could be abused".

However, it isn't knowledge that is being abused, but fact.  Your next sentences are not about misuse of knowledge but about presenting made-up "facts" as truth.

... you mean *pathological* liars.

P.P.S.  Your errand here is odd. You're looking for the perfect word. But if you do happen to find it, there will be no need to explain what it means with a defining *who*-clause.  The sentence that results will be much like "There are magicians who do magic tricks".

Comment: +1 for the advice. I need to improve my writing skills :)

Comment: In crude colloquial English, we say that a person who uses fake "facts" as you have described "pulled those numbers out of his ass".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a "poser".

synonyms:   exhibitionist, poseur, poseuse, self-publicist, attention-seeker

(https://www.google.pt/search?q=poser)

Answer (score 0):

The term I prefer is **Con-Artist**.  The ‘con’ is short for *confidence*. You can also call them a *shill*, or *grifter*. All three of these work. *Quack* is also good if you’re referring to someone who works in the medical industry.

P.S. I have a great respect for anyone who has trouble referring to con artists as ‘people’.  I have the very same issue.